# SP 2013 Search Result Distinct on Property

Tags: search, search-results

I am trying to search for **Document** item, following is the code that works fine:

```
static void SearchDocs()
{
    string url = "http://spsvr/";
    string searchText = @"IsDocument:1";

    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url))
    {
        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(siteCollection);
        keywordQuery.QueryText = searchText;

        SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
        ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

        var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
        var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();

        DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;

        PrintResult(dataTable);
    }
}
```

I want to limit the items returned one item ( document ) per user, so that I can get list of unique users involved with document items.

To describe more, consider getting list of users involved in document modification in last 5 days. The list of users should be distinct or unique returned by search result.

Comment: You mean that if there are 20 results by 10 different authors, you want 10 results by the 10 distinct authors?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes